# table already exists when adding a migration for identity

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a table called `Pages` in my database already since it comes from the `DbInitializer` class.

Now I want to add `Identity` to the project, I wanna add a migration so I did:

```
add-migration IdentityAdded -context CmsContext
```

Which worked after a bit of a struggle, but anyway now that I run:

```
update-database -context CmsContext
```

to update the database, I get the error:

```
There is already an object named 'Pages' in the database.
```

The `Pages` table does indeed exist, but can I somehow ignore that table and just update the database regardless of existing tables?

Comment: I dont know aps.net but you can create 2 tables with same name under different schemas of single database.

Comment: So this is your first migration? If you just want the differences you should have done an initial migration to just take a snapshot of your schema before making the tracked changes. For EF 6 it would be `add-migration MyBaseline -IgnoreChanges`. IAC, at this point just comment out the table creation from the Up() method of the migration and re-apply.

Comment: I think -ignorechanges doesn't work anymore, anyway I ended up commenting out relevant troublesome code in the migration file.